# Cannot select Python Environment on VS Code 1.22.2

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am trying to [set up Python Environment](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments) on VS Code 1.22.2 (Windows 10, v.1803) with the [Python extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) 2018.4.0. My problem is, that whatever I do, I can not get rid of the error in the Status Bar:

[image: Select Python Environment]

I have these in my User Settings:

```
  "python.venvPath": "C:/Python/VirtualEnv",
  "python.pythonPath": "C:/Python/VirtualEnv/myproject/Scripts/python.exe",
```

and I have tried both the forward slashes '`/`' and double backslashes '`\\`' as folder name separator.

When I Click the "Select Python Environment", I can see a list of virtual environments (from `C:/Python/VirtualEnv`). However, even if I select one, the status bar still says "Select Python Environment". Every time I try to select an virtual environment, the Terminal (Output -> Python) says

```
Linter 'pylint' is not installed. Please install it or select another linter".
Error: spawn c:\PATH_TO_WORKSPACE\src/venv/bin/python ENOENT
```

It clearly tries to start a python process from a wrong folder.
How should I try to fix this?

*Edit*:
Tried also disabling all the other extensions and restarting, with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

So it turned out that for some reason I had to delete and recreate the VS Code workspace, and after that the selection worked again. I'm leaving this here to perhaps save someone else's time in the future.